# Not getting back any data using axios and tv maze api

Tags: javascript, html, json, api, axios

I'm trying to get search data using the axios [plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios#response-schema) from the TV Maze [Api](https://www.tvmaze.com/api#show-search)

```
    <form method="POST" action="/results">
  <input type="text" name="searchTerm" placeholder="Search for shows">

  <input type="submit" value="Search">

</form>
```

I'm using a handlebar to post the information to my app.js

```
//Sets up results page
app.get("/results", mware.requireLogin, function(req, res) {

  const simplifiedUser = {
    username: req.user._doc.username, 
    isAdmin: req.user._doc.isAdmin
  };

  res.render("results", {
    message: req.flash('info'),
    user: simplifiedUser
  });
});

// Process the form submission
app.post('/results', async function(req, res) {

    const results = await showService.searchShows(req.body.searchTerm);
    if(results && results.shows) {
        res.render('results', {
            results: results.shows,
            searchTerm: req.body.searchTerm
        });
    } else {
        res.render('error');
    }

});
```

It then sends it off to retrieve that data but nothing is coming back. It keeps on skipping the data and goes straight ro rendering out the error message.

```
const showService = {

searchShows: async (term) => {
  //searches for shows
  //   /search/shows?q=query
  
    try {

      const options = {
      params: {
        term,
      }
  };

      const response = await axios.get(show_api + '/search/shows?q=', options);


    if(response && response.data){
      return response.data;
    } else {
      return ["did not work"];
    }
      //console.log(response);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error.response.data);
    }
  }
```

};

Any solution would help a lot thank you

Comment: I don't use axios but my guess is the URL is bad. Your code will generate something like `https://api.tvmaze.com/search/shows?q=&term=test`. You need to end the URL at `shows` and use `params: { q: term }` instead (edit: tested, works fine for me)

Comment: Dear OP, I am reviewer, please edit your question and place code in `code` blocks, currently your `};` is outside the blocks. Also don't add these thankful messages because stack overflow is a place where everybody is trying to be helpful so we avoid these kind of phrases. Take our [tour].